# Using Jira on subdomain and not 8080

Tags: proxypass, jira

I have Jira installed as a service on my Ubuntu VPS on 8080.  I've successfully used ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse to point http://jira.mydomain.com to http://mydomain.com:8080

However, after login, the URL in the browser is changed to http://mydomain.com:8080/Dashboard....  Is there anyway to keep the http://jira.mydomain.com even after login, and throughout the whole user experience?

Thanks,

Sam

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the Base URL hasn't been changed to point at the new server URL.

See https://confluence.atlassian.com/plugins/servlet/mobile#content/view/185729544 for details.